# Call a function after a first function is ran

Tags: jquery

I want to hide a div by clicking somewhere on the page but only if the div was first displayed by clicking on the preview.

I have this :

```
$(function() {  
    $("#videopreview").click(function() {
    $("#videolarge").css({ display: 'block' });
    $("#videopreview").css({ display: 'none' });

        $("#videolarge").click(function(){ return false; });
        $(document).one("click", function() { 
        $("#videolarge").css({ display: 'none' });
        $("#videopreview").css({ display: 'block' });

        });
    });
});
```

It runs the two functions in the same time so nothing happened :)

Update:

```
$(function() {  
$("#videopreview").click(function() {
    $("#videolarge").css({ display: 'block' });
    $("#videopreview").css({ display: 'none' });
});
$("#videolarge").click(function(){ return false; });
$("#videopreview").click(function(){ return false; });
$(document).click(function() { 
    $("#videolarge").css({ display: 'none' });
    $("#videopreview").css({ display: 'block' });
});
});
```

I can use remove() but once hidden I can't run it again (what makes sense). How can I handle it ?

Comment: Instead of anonymous functions, write two separate functions with names. Then you can see better how they are running, which calls which. If you add a flag (variable outside the two functions) that is zero until the preview has been clicked, and only then allows the other steps to occur, you may be on your way to solving your own problem.

Comment: You really need to explain the question as it is not very clear. Maybe give the markup and explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: I believe what's required is e.g. a thumbnail preview which will show the full video player when clicked. Once displayed, a click anywhere on the page will re-hide the video player and re-display the preview thumbnail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the event inside of another event function. That's not going to work.

Use this code instead:

```
$(function() {  
    $("#videopreview").click(function() {
        $("#videolarge").css({ display: 'block' });
        $("#videopreview").css({ display: 'none' });
    });
    $("#videolarge").click(function(){ return false; });
    $(document).one("click", function() { 
        $("#videolarge").css({ display: 'none' });
        $("#videopreview").css({ display: 'block' });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks to the previous answers I found a solution.
Now a new problem show up.

In my div, I run a video. When I hide with "display:none", the video is still running in the background. Can I resolve this with jquery or it is in the Youtube API side ?

Comment: @user1708580 take a look at [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) (I'm in iran so I can't see the site :() or you can take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839638/cant-figure-out-how-to-pause-youtube-video-on-click) or the best way is Google it!

Comment: Yes you are right, i'm using Youtube video. But I will use it for several video platform. So I was hopping to find a general solution with Jquery not each API.

Comment: @user1708580 I think there is no general way and you should do it for each api!

Comment: Ok thank you ! I found finally a solution which is to use .remove() and not just css

Comment: @user1708580 Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

If you attach both handlers right from the start, but in the document.click handler check if the large video is visible before trying to do anything, and also check that it wasn't the video preview that was clicked. Something like:

```
$(function()
{  
    $("#videopreview").on('click', function()
    {
        $("#videolarge").css({ display: 'block' });
        $("#videopreview").css({ display: 'none' });
    });

    $(document).on("click", function(e)
    {
        if ($("#videolarge").is(":visible") && e.target.id !== "videopreview")
        {
            $("#videolarge").css({ display: 'none' });
            $("#videopreview").css({ display: 'block' });
        }
    });
});
```

Side note: Instead of directly setting the CSS properties of the two elements, it might be neater and faster to have appropriate CSS classes that you can add or remove.